# Object instance outputs `undefined` for it's Prototype's property. Why?

Tags: javascript, constructor, function-prototypes

As per my understanding (though new to Javascript), Object instances inherit properties and methods of their prototypes. In the following, I explicitly set the Title object instance's prototype to `Foo()` and therefore Title should inherit Foo's property (bar) but `alert(Title.bar);` outputs `undefined` whereas it should (as per my understanding) output `Vanilla`. Obviously there is something amiss in my understanding, Can someone help me understand as to why  `alert(Title.bar);` outputs `undefined` whereas `alert(Title.prototype.bar);` outputs `Vanilla`.

```
 function Foo(name) {
    return this.bar = name;
   };

  Foo.prototype.append = function (what) { return this.bar += "" + what; }
  Foo.prototype.newbar = "Chocolate";

  function Title() {
        return function page_title() { return this.title = this.bar; }
  }

  //Setting Prototype of Title instance to Foo() 
     Title.prototype = new Foo('Vanilla');  

  //Setting Prototype's Constructor to Title() for proper inheritance
       Title.prototype.constructor = Title;

    //Calling Inherited variable(Prototype's) on the instance
     alert(Title.bar); // undefined
```

Comment: For some weird reason, you are `return`ing a function from your `Title` constructor. You won't be able to create instances that way, every time you call `new Title` you'll get a function only.

Comment: `Title` is not an instance, and does not inherit from `Title.prototype`!

Comment: I believe `Title` is because by defining a constructor (Title()), JS automatically creates an object of the same name. Pls correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, when you declare `Title`, JS does create a *constructor function object* (which inherits from `Function.prototype`). It doesn't instantiate a `Title` instance though. You would need to do `new Title` for that (if it worked, see my first comment)

Answer (score 0):

you can call it redirection but it can be done using this way :

> Title.prototype = new Foo("Vanilla");

then create another instance i.e

> var rek = Title.prototype

Now check the instance of **rek instanceof Foo** and **rek instanceof Foo** 
it will give you better understanding

alert(rek.bar) // gives your Vanilla

:)